# Reading string value from a text file into textView

Tags: android

I've been searching everywhere for a method that allows one to read a @string value from a text file. I'm not sure if I'm being entirely clear since I cannot seem to describe it in words so I'll use this snippet.

```
This is a <@string/square_root>
```

So when I read the file into a textview it includes the square root symbol with it.
Is this possible? or if there is another method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to put your string in a resource file, typically res/values/strings.xml  (Note below that 221A is the Unicode value of the square root symbol).

```
<string name="square_root">\u221A</string>
```

Then you can reference this string from either an XML layout file:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/square_root" ...>
```

Or from Java code:

```
Context context = this;  // in this example the current activity is the context
String title = context.getString(R.string.square_root);
TextEdit textEdit = ....
textEdit.setText(title);
```

For more information, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html